# WannaCry patch for Vista; says not applicable

Tags: wannacrypt

I have an old Vista laptop running Vista (32 bit).  I tried to install Microsoft's patch for WannaCry from http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4012598

When I try to install the Vista patch (not the 64-bit; the 3rd one in the list), it starts installing and then eventually says that it's not applicable to my computer.

Two weird things: 1) When I click the hyperlink that is the name of the patch, the page that comes up is in Spanish.  2) I can tell that the description box that comes up is describing the Win XP SP3 patch.

Has anyone else run in to this?

Comment: Is your OS completely up to date? And why did you download the XP version if you have Vista?

Comment: So you are using [this](http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/secu/2017/02/windows6.0-kb4012598-x86_13e9b3d77ba5599764c296075a796c16a85c745c.msu) patch?  If you do not have an English version of Vista installed then your installing the incorrect patch.

Comment: Usually "Not applicable" means you aren't running a version that needs that patch, typically because it (or a different update that includes the same code change) was already applied.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the guidance from Microsoft here:

"Customers who are running supported versions of the operating system (**Windows Vista**, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, Windows 10, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2016) will have received the security update MS17-010 in March. *If customers have automatic updates enabled or have installed the update, they are protected*. For other customers, we encourage them to install the update as soon as possible."

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/msrc/2017/05/12/customer-guidance-for-wannacrypt-attacks/